# Confusion in class-path entries in MANIFEST.MF file of a jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar `x.jar` and in its MANIFEST.MF file, I mentioned

```
 Class-Path: y.jar z.jar
```

I am deploying an application that uses `x.jar` on jboss.
Now what will happen if both  `y.jar` and  `z.jar` or any of these is absent in local network and if `y.jar` is present as `y.1.jar`. Any error or warning shown?

Comment: Your app uses the libraries on the classpath -- it doesn't care what the file containing those libraries is called as long as its on the classpath. Your network is of no importance here. If your libraries aren't on the classpath then your app may have problems and may not even start up (depending on how you use these libraries), or you may get other exceptions in your logs.

Comment: If I understand your question, the answer is;
If required jar is not present, while runtime it will throw class not found exception.

Comment: @EngineerDollery if I have two jars.. one with classpath entry y.jar and another with z.jar but i dont have y.jar in my libraries.. what will be the case while deploying in both cases? will it throw an exception or just a warning?

Comment: It's not as simple as @Pasupathi says. The results depend on how you're using the classes in the library. If you're just trying to do normal java, then you will get a class not found exception. If you're playing with classloaders and compile time weaving your results may vary. Also, you may have built a system where the jar is optional and loaded as a 'plugin' via osgi.

Comment: A jar doesn't have a classpath -- do you mean a dependency? We use jar dependencies as a clever way of getting classes loaded and it's the classes that really matter, not the jars. If the classes you depend on are on the classpath, no matter what the containing jar is called, then your app will work as expected, but if they're not then you should expect problems and maybe errors like the one described by @Pasupathi

Comment: Also, the manifest file is unimportant here.

Comment: @EngineerDollery .. I got your point.. and by "classpath".. i mean, the manifest file of the jar containing line "Class-path : x.jar y.jar".

Comment: Also.. if manifest file is unimportant for loading the classes.. why exactly do we add "Class-path : " in it?

Comment: I don't know why you're doing this. I assume you have your reasons, but manifest files are not usually required in jar files and classpath entries make no sense in that context. Also, 'Class-Path' specifically is totally meaningless (afaik).

Comment: @EngineerDollery .. I am not doing this.. In my application, I am having many jars (not mine.. ex: apache-utils.jar, etc) and these jars have MANIFEST file.. with classpath entries.. and I am geting warnings based on entries in them.. So, i just want to understand the logic behind it.. When I read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).. but I could not understand what happens if these jars are missing..

Comment: I know you're using jboss, but here's what Mulesoft have to say on the issue of manifest files in tomcat applications: "While this feature is supported by some web application servers, such as Weblogic, which may be why some users attempt to use it with Tomcat, specifying classpath using a Manifest file is not supported by Tomcat, nor is it part of the Servlet specification."